# Installing pgf-pie in macosCatalina (command line)

Tags: pdftex, pgf-pie, macos

I'm trying to install the `pgf-pie` package here in macOS Catalina 10.15

I've followed the steps:

1. downloaded `pgf-pie.sty` here: http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-pie/
2. used kpsewhich graphicx command to find where sty files are located. The output is here: `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty/`
3. in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`, I've created a `pgf-pie` folder in which I included `pgf-pie.sty`
4. in sequence, I used `texhash /usr/local/texlive/`

I thought it was going to work, but it didn't. Could anyone let me know if I did something wrong?

Comment: Hello, why don't you just do `\usepackage{pgf-pie}` and let you distribution do the work ? (I am quite unfamiliar with latex under macos)

Comment: it doesn't work. seems it cannot find the .sty file...

Comment: @BambOo AFAIK it is not an package that ships with the standard installations, and thus needs to be installed manually. Marcelo, I just copied the `pgf-pie.sty` file to some location in which LaTeX can find it such as the same directory as the file which one compiles, and that works for me.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat After seeing your comment I have to admit I did not check on my miktex first, but it is actually shipped with mitkex

Comment: @bamboo I see. It does not come with MacTeX/TeXLive it seems.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: MacTeX installs a complete TeX Live distribution as released. Of course things change over the year as is true for any TeX Live distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the TeX Live installed by MacTeX. Place the .sty file I your personal tree.That tree has its root in `~/Library/texmf` (`~/Library` is the Library folder in you HOME folder, NOT the one in the root of you HD) and is created by you. The create the nested folders `tex/latex` within the root and place the .sty file in a folder there.

You should NOT place things in texmf-dist.

Comment: it worked. thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the package: `https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie?lang=en`
2. Assuming you are using TexLive2020: Copy to `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex`
3. Open a terminal and execute the follows

   sudo mktexlsr

   sudo texhash
4. Recompile your `main.tex`

That's all : )